# Find $\int_\mathbb{R} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n} \cdot 1_{[-2^n,2^n]} \, d\lambda$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to determine:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n} \cdot 1_{[-2^n,2^n]} \, d\lambda$$

My idea is that:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n} \cdot 1_{[-2^n,2^n]} \, d\lambda$$
$$= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{3^n} \cdot 1_{[-2^n,2^n]} \, d\lambda$$
$$= \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{3^n} \cdot 2\cdot2^n$$
$$= 2\cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{2^n}{3^n} $$
$$= \frac{2}{1-2/3}-2=6-2=4$$

However a friend of mine is getting 8/3 and we cannot agree on the right result

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your answer is correct.